# Moving element via javascript on mouse move

Tags: javascript, element, onmousemove

I have link right [Here](http://www.alaskavodka.com/) which is a site. As you can see, there's bottle in the center and moving relying on users mouse move and I only know that's using css transform .. but not much...How can I create such a thing?
any tutorial or smth...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are searching for something like a Parallax Effect on Mouse movement.

Have a look at:

- http://www.rleonardi.com/tutorial-animation/

There are even jQuery Plugins:

- http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('html').mousemove()` function to detect the mouse moving over the page.
You can find an example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/)